# Advice on connecting a Li-Po battery to SMD terminal?

Tags: pcb, components, surface-mount, lipo

I would like to connect a Li-Po battery pack with female PH connector such as the one shown below to a PCB which will use SMD devices. I have also provided the circuit diagram below and highlighted the section with the battery connection below. I didn't have much luck finding a SMD male PH connector on lcsc.com where I will be ordering components from. Obviously any connector can be used as I can just remove the PH connector and attach another one. I would like to know what sort of connectors are generally used to connect Li-Po batteries to SMD PCBs. What would be the most convenient connection part for this application?

[image: Circuit]

[image: Li-Po battery example]

Comment: You know that you can have through hole on such boards too?

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I'm extremely new to PCB design so I wasn't sure if it was advisable or not. I assume that combining through hole and smd will push up the board fabrication cost due to the drilling of the boards?

Comment: they have to drill the vias too, so just ask for a quote.